# ElectronJS: how to clear all cookies from a session?

Tags: electron

I am creating cookies using the code given below:

```
///Cookie
let cookie = {
    url: 'http://www.example.com',
    name: 'oauthDetailsGoogle',
    value: JSON.stringify(oauthDetailsGoogle),
    expirationDate: oauthDetailsGoogle.accessTokenExpireDateTime
};

///save cookie
electronConstants().mySession.cookies.set(cookie, (error) => {

    ///if error then return error
    if (error) {
        defer.reject(error);
    }
    ///return null if no error
    else {
        defer.resolve(true);
    }
});
```

In order to delete cookies I am using the following code:

```
electronConstants().mySession.cookies.remove('http://www.example.com', 'oauthDetailsGoogle', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

Suppose I have created 10 cookes so in order to delete 10 cookes I will have to call the remove function 10 time with the specific details?

Please guide.. 
Many thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution in Electron Documentation: [`clearStorageData()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/session#sesclearstoragedataoptions)

Here is the function that clears everything in one go:

```
electronConstants().mySession.clearStorageData([], function (data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

The first parameter takes `options` so you can customize what you want to clear. Refer the documentation link that I provided above.

Comment: this worked for me with electron v1.4.13: `session.defaultSession.clearStorageData([], (data) => {})`